# Definition of absolute value for complex

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is correct for complex numbers in disk $\mathbb{D}(0,1)$  $$\sqrt{(1-z^{2})^{2}} = |1-z^{2}|$$

How to prove them?

I need compute $\frac{-(1+z^{2}) + |1-z^{2}|}{2z}$

For real numbers I use fact that $z \in [-1,1]$ and it's easy.

How to simplify for complex numbers?

Comment: What is the left hand side supposed to mean if $(1 - z^2)^2$ is not a non-negative real number? For example, if $z = \left(\sqrt3 + i\right)/2$, then $z^2 = \left(1 + \sqrt3i\right)/2$, so $z^2 - 1 = \left(-1 + \sqrt3i\right)/2$, and $(z^2 - 1)^2 = \left(-1 - \sqrt3i\right)/2$. The left hand side is then ambiguous. Also, however it is interpreted, its value cannot be the real number on the right hand side (which is $1$, not that that makes any difference).

Answer (score 0):

The formula is incorrect. Let $z=(-5+4i)/7$. Then $z^2=(9-40i)/49$ so that
$$
(1-z^2)^2 = 2\left(\frac{40}{49}\right)^2 i,
$$
which cannot have a real number as a square root.

However, if you meant to write
$$
\sqrt{|1-z^2|^2}=|1-z^2|
$$
then this is correct, since $|1-z^2|$ is a positive real number it is a consequence of the identity $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ which holds for all positive real numbers $a$.